# No display data table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have an issue with displaying data to table in index.blade.php. 
Here is my source 'PhongController.js':

```
var app = angular.module('ql-ktx',['ngMaterial'],
 function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
 }).constant('API','http://localhost:1000/');

app.controller('PhongController',function($scope,$http,API){
    $http.get(API+'phong').then(successCallback);
    function successCallback(response){
        $scope.phongs=response;
    //success code
};
```

And this is my source from index.blade.php :

```
    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding" ng-controller="PhongController"
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tbody><tr>
                      <th>Mã Phòng</th>
                      <th>Tên Phòng</th>
                      <th>Số người</th>
                      <th>Khu</th>
                      <th>Loại phòng</th>
                    </tr>
           </tbody>
<tbody>
                     <tr ng-repeat="p in phongs" >
                      <td><% p.p_ma %></td>
                      <td><% p.p_ten %></td>
                      <td><% p.p_soNguoi %></td>
                      <td><% p.khu.k_ten %></td>
                      <td><% $p.loaiphong.lp_ten %></td>

                    </tr>

                  </tbody></table>
                </div>
```

So, i wrote in file Route/Web.php as: `Route::get('phong','PhongController@index')`.
And my source from PhongController.php is:

```
  public function index()
    {
        $dsphong=Phong::ALL();
        return view('backend.phong.index')->with('dsphong',$dsphong);
        //
    }
```

I attempt to try many times, but it's not working, mean it doesn't display database . Any Helps for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a standard HTTP response object of AngularJS. To get the response data received from server out of it, you need to get it using `response.data` key. Change your `successCallback` as below:

```
function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.phongs = response.data;
};
```

Note that my answer assumes that the HTTP call succeeds and a well-formed response is received on the client. If not, then the question needs to be updated with more details.

Comment: i got it using response.data key. But it isn't still displaying data.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(response)` when you put it has first line of `successCallback`? Please update the output in the question.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @ThanhToàn -- I need to see what is received in `response` in `successCallback` function. Just write `console.log(response)` in `successCallback` function, and post the output here.

Comment: When i tried to do it, it happens : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list and https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=PhongController

Comment: @ThanhToàn -- I cannot help you further with this without looking at your code. You can try creating a fiddle or plunker to replicate this issue. I will take a look on it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know PHP but I know angularJS
I don't what do you mean by typing <% %>
in angularjs to show value of scope into view you must use {{ variabileNameWithOutscope. }}

try to edit in

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in phongs" >
    <td> {{p.p_ma}}  </td>
    <td> {{p.p_ten}}  </td>
    <td> {{p.p_soNguoi}}  </td>
    <td> {{p.khu.k_ten}}  </td>
    <td> {{p.loaiphong.lp_ten}}  </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: OP has configured `$interpolateProvider` with custom tokens.

Comment: Oh, i know but I define" <% %> "to specialize in using Angularjs, and "{{ }}" this is used by Laravel.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: ok sorry I never used interpolateProvider service, if you make a jsFiddle I can help you